# exoplayer precaching streams causing performance problems

Tags: android, performance, exoplayer

Using exoplayer 2.8.1, testing on android API version 22.  I construct a cache and data source factories using the following code:

```
private static final long DEFAULT_MAX_CACHE_SIZE = 20*1024*1024L;

cacheEvictor = new LeastRecentlyUsedCacheEvictor(DEFAULT_MAX_CACHE_SIZE);

cache = new SimpleCache(
        new File(context.getExternalCacheDir(), "exoplayer-cache"),
        cacheEvictor);

uncachedDataSourceFactory = new OkHttpDataSourceFactory(
        new OkHttpClient(),
        "Android.ExoPlayer",
        null);
dataSourceFactory =
        new CacheDataSourceFactory(
                cache,
                uncachedDataSourceFactory);
```

I then precache standard HTTP audio content using the following code:

```
new Thread (new Runnable () {
    public void run() {
        try {
            CacheUtil.cache(
                    new DataSpec(uri, DataSpec.FLAG_ALLOW_CACHING_UNKNOWN_LENGTH | DataSpec.FLAG_ALLOW_GZIP),
                    cache,
                    uncachedDataSourceFactory.createDataSource(),
                    null,
                    null);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            callback.invoke(false, "Error: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            callback.invoke(false, "Download interrupted");
        }
        callback.invoke(true);
    }
}).start();
```

This works fine on an emulator, however when attempting to do this on an actual phone the phone becomes very unresponsive while the cached item is being downloaded (animations drop to about 4-5 frames per second, scrolling is jittery).  Why is this making the system so slow, and how can I make it work more smoothly?

Comment: You have a repo to check out? How big is the file size you usually cache? Might it make more sense to use a service for downloading files in the background?

Comment: No.  Around 10-20MB; the file I was testing with is 14MB.  I'm not sure how a service would help -- I only start downloading while my UI is visible, and don't generally care if the process is stopped part way through, and I don't believe there are any performance related differences in using a service vs a background thread.

Comment: I understand that you dispatched the thread (fire and forget) and the UI thread slows down to 5 f/s. On emulator it works fine but on your actual phone it does not.
Can you tell us more about the phone? Did you try with another phone or tablet ?

I was also thinking that maybe the emulator uses WiFi connection. I assume the phone does so too ?

Comment: Have tested on multiple phones, including: IMO Q2, Samsung Galaxy S6 and S7, all using wifi connections (my code is arranged so that the precaching isn't called unless the phone is connected to wifi).

Comment: Maybe the thread operates at the same priority level as the UI thread and this causes a slow down too. I read about it here: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr
Section starting with **If you implement Thread or HandlerThread...** In this case lower the priority, as described in the text. I am curious if that is the solution (my feeling is yes...)